# PLACEHOLDER - Best of CGCC

Tags: app, placeholder

A StackApp that uses [this account](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110291/gingerbot) to perform tasks related to Code Golf Stack Exchange's annual Best Of CGCC event. This app is not designed to be used by any account besides that one. (This post is being made to enable write access in the API)